# Google play console closed testing not sending emails

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to publish an app to the play store but need to test it first. I've been staring at this for several days and don't know why the closed testing won't send any emails to the testers I've listed. Here are some screenshots, please let me know if you need any more information.

[image: Screenshot1]

[image]

[image: Screenshot3]

[image: Screenshto4]
[image: screenshot5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play console does not send the email. You need to send them the link:[image]

You can get the link by pressing copy link.

Comment: bruh moment....

Comment: In closed testing, do you have to ask every tester for their Play account email and manually add it to the testers list, or is just sending the link enough?

Comment: Yes, otherwise they will get the message `App not available for this account`. In the past you didn't have to ask everyone for their email, as there was an option to create a Google+ group of testers, but since Google+ was shutdown, getting all the testers' emails is the only option if you don't want to create an open test.